# Does a memory corruption on one OS but not the other implies programming error?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, memory-corruption

I am working on a project where I need to use someone else's code at some point.

However, the tests I ran gives me strange results. On one OS, the code seems to run fine, but on the other there seems to be a problem.

I tried to track down the problem and found a loop in which the problem can be solved by adding a `write` statement. I suspected a memory corruption so that I did the following:

Assume there are 3 variables accessed in the loop:

```
integer a(100),b(100),c(100)
```

I have added 1 more variable

```
integer a(100),b(100),dummyvar,c(100)
```

Then I set the `dummyvar` to `0` at the first line of the codes. When I printed the `dummyvar` at the end of the program, the value of the `dummyvar` at the end of the program was the last value of variable `c`. The codes are too long to bruteforce for finding what causes this issue.

So far I have tried:

1. Checking the boundaries of arrays and subroutines manually (as much as I could) to spot a possible out of array problem.
2. Using compiler parameters such as `-fpe0 -traceback` etc...

Before reporting to my supervisor what I need to know is: **Does failing of code in one setup but not on the other CERTAINLY implies there is a problem with the code? Or it may be somehow related to libraries, OS etc?**

The setup in which the code "seems to" run fine is:

- CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
- Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE
  for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 13.0.1.117 Build
  20121010

The setup in which the code fails is:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 17.0.1.132 Build 20161005

Finally, GNU compiler works fine on both computers in spite of having different versions.

Comment: *Checking the boundaries of arrays and subroutines manually (as much as I could) to spot a possible out of array problem.*  Refer to your compiler manual to find out how to have the compiler generate code to do this at run time, it will be much more thorough than your 'manual' efforts.  Check also the possible use of variables before they are given values, again your compiler will help.  There are other possibilities, but those two are probably the best guesses to start work on.

Comment: As to "certainly" bad code: no.  But the odds are good.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the ideas. I particularly find the dummy variable getting the last element of the next array interesting. I hope the documentation will clarify it.

Comment: Another tool you can use is electric fence.  There's a [forum question](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/270936) on the Intel boards that offers some advice on tracking down this sort of thing.